# Previous textbox is filled with value of the successor when navigating back in browser

Tags: google-chrome, kendo-ui, navigation, back-button

i have weird problem, which seems not to be related to any functionality of my code - no values sent in URL, no some tricky initializations, no cache turned on...

I have a bunch of kendo web controls acting as a filter criteria when sending request to server.
I do search:

[image: How it looks before submitting]

I get some result on new redirected page. I press BACK in my Chrome browser. Voila, magic - the field value is shifted to the previous control and it happens to any couple of adjacent textboxes:

[image: The field value is shifted to the previous control!]

The controls markup looks trivial like this:

```
<div id="_bPX" class="cp-a"><input id="_bPW" type="text" value="" class="k-textbox"></div>
```

DOM IDs are generated automatically random based on some rules and are unique.

P.S: I've put breakpoint in inline javascript, which deals with **Invoice no** and **Reservation no** textboxes. But none of it triggered when I come to the page after pressing BACK...

[Page markup](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgkpbwg13r5m5ze/Search%20purchases.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Is this only happening with the Reservation No and Invoice No fields? Do they have different id's? Please add your code to your original post if you can. That will help us give you a better answer.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the question. The project itself is pretty big, there is C# framework built over kendo js UI, which creates tons of JS markup. I am attaching page source, sorry for big volume, maybe you will manage to see the root of the problem in it - because i wasn't.

Comment: Is Chrome AutoFill turned on, or any other add-ons active ? Does any javascript run populating fields from a session restoration mechanism involving local storage, cookies or network activity ?  Does the same 'shift' occur if you clear all browser cache prior to submit and go back ?

Comment: @Richard Autofill was on, but when I turned it off - the problem did not go away. I do not have any extensions, related to form filling. Session and local storage is empty for this site, I've checked Dev tools tab. When i clear browser cache and do submit -> back, the problem is still there. And, finally, looking at page source attached, there is no anything in inline javascript, that could fill those fields...

Answer (score 0):

So far I have resolved this issue by adding autocomplete="off" for specific controls. Seems like it works both in IE and Chrome.